# How to map model object attributes with xhtml form in jsf?

Tags: spring, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

In spring we can map the model object attributes to UI form elements. How could this mapping be done in JSF? What is the topic name of this as discussed in JSF tutorials? We can manipulate mapped model object attributes in JSP page. Is it possible in an xhtml page too?

sample of spring example requested in the comment.

User domain object is mapped to the jsp form in controller like following sample code. Before this mapping was done as `command` in servlet xml. Now we can do it in controller itself.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView user() {
          return new ModelAndView("user", "command", new User());
       }





@RequestMapping(value = "/createuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")User user, 
           ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("name", user.getName());
    model.addAttribute("country", user.getCountry());
    model.addAttribute("id", user.getId());
    userService.saveUser(user);
    return "results";
}
```

Since we have mapped the object in controller we can manipulate the attribute as follows in jsp

```
    <form:form method="POST" action="/HibernateExample/createuser">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="country">Country</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="country" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

Class User

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
```

Comment: Post a sample using Spring's model mapping and I can give the JSF equivalent. As it stands now, your question is too abstract.

Comment: I have edited the question and added sample code for how object mapped. Please let me know how to achieve this in JSF. Appreciate if you could provide a jsf tutorial link which covers JSF fully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSF**

```
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="name" />
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{fooController.name}" />
        <!--...-->

        <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{fooController.doSaveUser()}" />
    </h:form>
```

**Logic (ManagedBean)**

```
@Named //@ManagedScoped if you don't use CDI
@RequestScoped //Or a different scope (e.g. @SessionScoped)
public class FooController {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void doSaveUser() {
        //Save user...
    }

}
```

I think you should read this [blog](http://balusc.blogspot.ch/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#CreateJSFHelloWorldInEclipseTheModel) of BalusC or anything else from him first.

Comment: I managed with this. I spent sometime to cover these things up and found tutorials too. Anyways Thank you